# Control Visibility of Paragraph Without Fields

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I'm preprocessing a paragraph to add a custom form but I'm having trouble with the visibility. I don't need any fields on this paragraph.

If I just add the form to the paragraph the whole paragraph is hidden for anonymous users.

```
function my_module_preprocess_paragraph__my_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\my_module\Form\MyCustomForm');
  $variables['content']['form'] = $form;
}
```

However, if I add a title field to that paragraph everything shows up fine. Is there a way I can get the form to show without having to add fields?

Comment: You can use hook_field_widget_form_alter and hide the fields with #access FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Implement [hook_field_widget_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/8.2.x)

It will give control of paragraph fields.

```
function hook_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'xyz') {
    $element['subform']['field_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```